# Use input pipe and manage keyboard

Tags: pipe, keyboard, php, stdin

I try to run a PHP script which read a flow by incoming pipe, and I want to manage the keyboard too : **cat /etc/passwd|./readSlow.php**
The script will read each character from pipe and display it slowly on stdout until the user press the 'q' key (without pressing RETURN).
Actually, the script read the pipe and display the text slowly. But it doesn't stop when I press the 'q' (it display it and I need to press the RETURN key after the 'q' to activate the stop).

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// ReadSlow

// This tool take a file in input and read it, character by caracter to the
// output.
// It add a sleep time between each character.

// Wait 0.2s between each char
$defaultSpeed = 0.5;

if (($input = fopen ("php://stdin", "r")) === false)
  die ("Can not open stdin\n");
if (($keyboard = fopen("/dev/tty", "r")) === false)
  die ("Can not open /dev/tty\n");
stream_set_blocking($keyboard, false);

$speed = $defaultSpeed;

while (($char = fgetc ($input)) !== false)
{
  if (($key = fgetc ($keyboard)) === "q") // get input from keyboard
    break;
  usleep ($speed * 1000000);
  echo "$char";
}
 
fclose ($input);
```

At the end I would like to have more keys available.

**Question :** How should I mix the pipe in stdin and the keyboard (to not display the pressed key, to not waiting the return press) ?

I try to play with "stty", but each time, I have "stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device"

I am on Linux, with Bash if it change something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Terminal/console aka 'tty' devices on Unix by default work in line-at-a-time mode, to allow you an opportunity to correct small typing mistakes. You need to turn this off and `stty` is a good way to do so -- but `stty` operates on its stdin, and you have redirected stdin (with the pipe) so you need to redirect it back for `stty`. Try `system("stty </dev/tty raw")` at the beginning of your program and similarly but with `-raw` at the end.

Comment: And I add the -echo/echo to not display the typed key ! Awesome ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that stdin and tty are the same input channel. If you can get away without a pipe, try below code via "**./readSlow.php /etc/passwd**". This takes the file to print  as a command line argument. The command "stty -echo" suppresses the output of the pressed keystroke.

```php
    #!/usr/bin/php
    <?php
    // ReadSlow
    
    // This tool take a file in input and read it, character by caracter to the
    // output.
    // It add a sleep time between each character.
    
    // Wait 0.2s between each char
    $defaultSpeed = 0.5;
    
    if (($input = fopen ($argv[1], "r")) === false)
      die ("Can not open $argv[1]\n");
    if (($keyboard = fopen("/dev/tty", "r")) === false)
      die ("Can not open /dev/tty\n");
    stream_set_blocking($keyboard, false);
    
    system("stty -echo");
    
    $speed = $defaultSpeed;
    
    while (($char = fgetc ($input)) !== false)
    {
      if (($key = fgetc ($keyboard)) === "q") // get input from keyboard
        break;
      usleep ($speed * 1000000);
      echo "$char";
    }
    
    fclose ($input);
    echo "\n";
    system("stty echo");
```

Comment: This is incorrect; _usually_ stdin is the same as tty, but when stdin has been redirected (in this case by a pipe) /dev/tty is still the tty. Also `stty -echo` is not enough to get character-at-a-time input.

Comment: The -echo/echo remove the key displayed but must be linked to raw/-raw to catch the key without pressing the RETURN key. Thanks a lot

Comment: The call to _stream_set_blocking($keyboard, false);_ for the tty catches the pressed key without having to press the RETURN key.